# How to pad image such that the frame has the same size?

Tags: floats

This example generates me the figure below. The frame for the left-most image is not the same as the rest. I would like to pad the image from below such that the frame is similar to the rest.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{tikz}% loads graphicx
\usepackage{graphicx,xcolor}

\begin{document}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\definetrim}[2]{%
  \define@key{Gin}{#1}[]{\setkeys{Gin}{trim=#2,clip}}%
}
\makeatother

\definetrim{kit_mocap}{0 0 0 3cm} % {left bottom right top}
%\def\barheight{0.015}
\def\imagewidth{0.12\textwidth}
\def\imagehspace{\hspace{-0.25em}}

\NewDocumentCommand{\frameincludegraphicsred}{O{}m}{%
  \begingroup
  \sbox{0}{\includegraphics[#1]{#2}}%
  \setlength{\fboxrule}{0.3mm}% exaggerated to better see the effect
  \setlength{\fboxsep}{-\fboxrule}%
  \makebox[0pt][l]{\usebox{0}}%
  \textcolor{red}{\fbox{\rule{0pt}{\ht0}\rule{\wd0}{0pt}}}%
  \endgroup
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\frameincludegraphicsblue}{O{}m}{%
  \begingroup
  \sbox{0}{\includegraphics[#1]{#2}}%
  \setlength{\fboxrule}{0.3mm}% exaggerated to better see the effect
  \setlength{\fboxsep}{-\fboxrule}%
  \makebox[0pt][l]{\usebox{0}}%
  \textcolor{blue}{\fbox{\rule{0pt}{\ht0}\rule{\wd0}{0pt}}}%
  \endgroup
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\frameincludegraphicsblack}{O{}m}{%
  \begingroup
  \sbox{0}{\includegraphics[#1]{#2}}%
  \setlength{\fboxrule}{0.1mm}% exaggerated to better see the effect
  \setlength{\fboxsep}{-\fboxrule}%
  \makebox[0pt][l]{\usebox{0}}%
  \textcolor{black}{\fbox{\rule{0pt}{\ht0}\rule{\wd0}{0pt}}}%
  \endgroup
}

\begin{figure*}[ht]
\centering
\subfloat{
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
    \node[anchor=south east,inner sep=0] (image) at (0,0) {\frameincludegraphicsblue[width=\imagewidth,kit_mocap]{example-image-a}};
    \begin{scope}[x={(image.south east)},y={(image.north west)}]
        \node[anchor=south east,draw,fill=white] at (0,0) {Pred};
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}}\imagehspace
\subfloat{
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
    \node[anchor=south east,inner sep=0] (imageb) at (0,0) {\frameincludegraphicsblue[width=\imagewidth,clip]{example-image-a}};
    \begin{scope}[x={(image.south east)},y={(image.north west)}]
        \node[anchor=south east,draw,fill=white] at (0,0) {True};
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}}\imagehspace
\subfloat{
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
    \node[anchor=south east,inner sep=0] (image) at (0,0) {\frameincludegraphicsblue[width=\imagewidth,clip]{example-image-a}};
    \begin{scope}[x={(image.south east)},y={(image.north west)}]
        \node[anchor=south east,draw,fill=white] at (0,0) {Pred};
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}}\imagehspace
\subfloat{
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
    \node[anchor=south east,inner sep=0] (imaged) at (0,0) {\frameincludegraphicsblue[width=\imagewidth,clip]{example-image-a}};
    \begin{scope}[x={(image.south east)},y={(image.north west)}]
        \node[anchor=south east,draw,fill=white] at (0,0) {True};
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}}\imagehspace
\subfloat{
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
    \node[anchor=south east,inner sep=0] (image) at (0,0) {\frameincludegraphicsred[width=\imagewidth,clip]{example-image-a}};
    \begin{scope}[x={(image.south east)},y={(image.north west)}]
        \node[anchor=south east,draw,fill=white] at (0,0) {Pred};
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}}\imagehspace
\subfloat{
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
    \node[anchor=south east,inner sep=0] (image6) at (0,0) {\frameincludegraphicsred[width=\imagewidth,clip]{example-image-a}};
    \begin{scope}[x={(image.south east)},y={(image.north west)}]
        \node[anchor=south east,draw,fill=white] at (0,0) {True};
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}}\imagehspace
\subfloat{
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
    \node[anchor=south east,inner sep=0] (image) at (0,0) {\frameincludegraphicsred[width=\imagewidth,clip]{example-image-a}};
    \begin{scope}[x={(image.south east)},y={(image.north west)}]
        \node[anchor=south east,draw,fill=white] at (0,0) {Pred};
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}}\imagehspace
\subfloat{
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
    \node[anchor=south east,inner sep=0] (image) at (0,0) {\frameincludegraphicsred[width=\imagewidth,clip]{example-image-a}};
    \begin{scope}[x={(image.south east)},y={(image.north west)}]
        \node[anchor=south east,draw,fill=white] at (0,0) {True};
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}}

\end{figure*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

This is how it should look like. The image (black box) has been pushed up, or padded from below. The text box stays exactly where it should be. The frame is the same as the rest.

[image]

Comment: Instead `\ht0` in `\rule{0pt}{\ht0}` you can use a height you want.

Comment: @Kong: Take this opportunity to reduce your code to something minimal. You've included large sets of the same image inclusion in your last 5 questions, when only one or two is needed. Consumption of the problem is far quicker when the code is reproducible and minimal.

Comment: @Werner sorry, that code is as closest as possible to what I have as I am worried that the solution, when incorporated into my code doesn't work due to incompatibilities etc, which has happened before.

Comment: @Kong: In this case, I can't see your issue dealing with *coloured frames*, or the need for 8 images when 2 should suffice.

Comment: my previous question regarding frames had a solution using \fbox which prevented my 8 figures from fitting on a single row. Who knows what "vertical padding" on an image could do when put beside a row of 7 other figures each with their own text box. As a user who still cant grasp the syntax after many years, its safer for me to show a MWE as close to my version as possible. Sorry again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I've added one more optional argument to the `\frameincludegraphics…` commands and used it to optionally set a different height:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{tikz}% loads graphicx
\usepackage{graphicx,xcolor}


\makeatletter
\newcommand{\definetrim}[2]{%
  \define@key{Gin}{#1}[]{\setkeys{Gin}{trim=#2,clip}}%
}
\makeatother

\definetrim{kit_mocap}{0 0 0 3cm} % {left bottom right top}
%\def\barheight{0.015}
\def\imagewidth{0.12\textwidth}
\def\imagehspace{\hspace{-0.25em}}

\NewDocumentCommand{\frameincludegraphicsred}{O{}mO{\ht0}}{%
  \begingroup
  \sbox{0}{\includegraphics[#1]{#2}}%
  \setlength{\fboxrule}{0.3mm}% exaggerated to better see the effect
  \setlength{\fboxsep}{-\fboxrule}%
  \makebox[0pt][l]{\usebox{0}}%
  \textcolor{red}{\fbox{\rule{0pt}{#3}\rule{\wd0}{0pt}}}%
  \endgroup
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\frameincludegraphicsblue}{O{}mO{\ht0}}{%
  \begingroup
  \sbox{0}{\includegraphics[#1]{#2}}%
  \setlength{\fboxrule}{0.3mm}% exaggerated to better see the effect
  \setlength{\fboxsep}{-\fboxrule}%
  \makebox[0pt][l]{\usebox{0}}%
  \textcolor{blue}{\fbox{\rule{0pt}{#3}\rule{\wd0}{0pt}}}%
  \endgroup
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\frameincludegraphicsblack}{O{}mO{\ht0}}{%
  \begingroup
  \sbox{0}{\includegraphics[#1]{#2}}%
  \setlength{\fboxrule}{0.1mm}% exaggerated to better see the effect
  \setlength{\fboxsep}{-\fboxrule}%
  \makebox[0pt][l]{\usebox{0}}%
  \textcolor{black}{\fbox{\rule{0pt}{#3}\rule{\wd0}{0pt}}}%
  \endgroup
}

\newlength{\wantedheight}

\begin{document}

\settoheight{\wantedheight}{\includegraphics[width=\imagewidth,clip]{example-image-a}}

\begin{figure*}[ht]
\centering
\subfloat{
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
    \node[anchor=south east,inner sep=0] (image) at (0,0) {\frameincludegraphicsblue[width=\imagewidth,kit_mocap]{example-image-a}[\wantedheight]};
    \begin{scope}[x={(image.south east)},y={(image.north west)}]
        \node[anchor=south east,draw,fill=white] at (0,0) {Pred};
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}}\imagehspace
\subfloat{
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
    \node[anchor=south east,inner sep=0] (imageb) at (0,0) {\frameincludegraphicsblue[width=\imagewidth,clip]{example-image-a}};
    \begin{scope}[x={(image.south east)},y={(image.north west)}]
        \node[anchor=south east,draw,fill=white] at (0,0) {True};
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}}\imagehspace
\subfloat{
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
    \node[anchor=south east,inner sep=0] (image) at (0,0) {\frameincludegraphicsblue[width=\imagewidth,clip]{example-image-a}};
    \begin{scope}[x={(image.south east)},y={(image.north west)}]
        \node[anchor=south east,draw,fill=white] at (0,0) {Pred};
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}}\imagehspace
\subfloat{
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
    \node[anchor=south east,inner sep=0] (imaged) at (0,0) {\frameincludegraphicsblue[width=\imagewidth,clip]{example-image-a}};
    \begin{scope}[x={(image.south east)},y={(image.north west)}]
        \node[anchor=south east,draw,fill=white] at (0,0) {True};
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}}\imagehspace
\subfloat{
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
    \node[anchor=south east,inner sep=0] (image) at (0,0) {\frameincludegraphicsred[width=\imagewidth,clip]{example-image-a}};
    \begin{scope}[x={(image.south east)},y={(image.north west)}]
        \node[anchor=south east,draw,fill=white] at (0,0) {Pred};
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}}\imagehspace
\subfloat{
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
    \node[anchor=south east,inner sep=0] (image6) at (0,0) {\frameincludegraphicsred[width=\imagewidth,clip]{example-image-a}};
    \begin{scope}[x={(image.south east)},y={(image.north west)}]
        \node[anchor=south east,draw,fill=white] at (0,0) {True};
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}}\imagehspace
\subfloat{
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
    \node[anchor=south east,inner sep=0] (image) at (0,0) {\frameincludegraphicsred[width=\imagewidth,clip]{example-image-a}};
    \begin{scope}[x={(image.south east)},y={(image.north west)}]
        \node[anchor=south east,draw,fill=white] at (0,0) {Pred};
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}}\imagehspace
\subfloat{
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
    \node[anchor=south east,inner sep=0] (image) at (0,0) {\frameincludegraphicsred[width=\imagewidth,clip]{example-image-a}};
    \begin{scope}[x={(image.south east)},y={(image.north west)}]
        \node[anchor=south east,draw,fill=white] at (0,0) {True};
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}}

\end{figure*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You can also define commands for top aligned or centered (smaller) images in the frame:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{tikz}% loads graphicx
\usepackage{graphicx,xcolor}


\makeatletter
\newcommand{\definetrim}[2]{%
  \define@key{Gin}{#1}[]{\setkeys{Gin}{trim=#2,clip}}%
}
\makeatother

\definetrim{kit_mocap}{0 0 0 3cm} % {left bottom right top}
%\def\barheight{0.015}
\def\imagewidth{0.12\textwidth}
\def\imagehspace{\hspace{-0.25em}}

\NewDocumentCommand{\frameincludegraphicsred}{O{}mO{\ht0}}{%
  \begingroup
  \sbox{0}{\includegraphics[#1]{#2}}%
  \setlength{\fboxrule}{0.3mm}% exaggerated to better see the effect
  \setlength{\fboxsep}{-\fboxrule}%
  \makebox[0pt][l]{\usebox{0}}%
  \textcolor{red}{\fbox{\rule{0pt}{#3}\rule{\wd0}{0pt}}}%
  \endgroup
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\frameincludegraphicsblue}{O{}mO{\ht0}}{%
  \begingroup
  \sbox{0}{\includegraphics[#1]{#2}}%
  \setlength{\fboxrule}{0.3mm}% exaggerated to better see the effect
  \setlength{\fboxsep}{-\fboxrule}%
  \makebox[0pt][l]{\usebox{0}}%
  \textcolor{blue}{\fbox{\rule{0pt}{#3}\rule{\wd0}{0pt}}}%
  \endgroup
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\frameincludegraphicsblack}{O{}mO{\ht0}}{%
  \begingroup
  \sbox{0}{\includegraphics[#1]{#2}}%
  \setlength{\fboxrule}{0.1mm}% exaggerated to better see the effect
  \setlength{\fboxsep}{-\fboxrule}%
  \makebox[0pt][l]{\usebox{0}}%
  \textcolor{black}{\fbox{\rule{0pt}{#3}\rule{\wd0}{0pt}}}%
  \endgroup
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\frameincludegraphicsredtop}{O{}mO{\ht0}}{%
  \begingroup
  \sbox{0}{\includegraphics[#1]{#2}}%
  \setlength{\fboxrule}{0.3mm}% exaggerated to better see the effect
  \setlength{\fboxsep}{-\fboxrule}%
  \makebox[0pt][l]{\raisebox{\dimexpr #3-\ht0\relax}{\usebox{0}}}%
  \textcolor{red}{\fbox{\rule{0pt}{#3}\rule{\wd0}{0pt}}}%
  \endgroup
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\frameincludegraphicsbluetop}{O{}mO{\ht0}}{%
  \begingroup
  \sbox{0}{\includegraphics[#1]{#2}}%
  \setlength{\fboxrule}{0.3mm}% exaggerated to better see the effect
  \setlength{\fboxsep}{-\fboxrule}%
  \makebox[0pt][l]{\raisebox{\dimexpr #3-\ht0\relax}{\usebox{0}}}%
  \textcolor{blue}{\fbox{\rule{0pt}{#3}\rule{\wd0}{0pt}}}%
  \endgroup
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\frameincludegraphicsblacktop}{O{}mO{\ht0}}{%
  \begingroup
  \sbox{0}{\includegraphics[#1]{#2}}%
  \setlength{\fboxrule}{0.1mm}% exaggerated to better see the effect
  \setlength{\fboxsep}{-\fboxrule}%
  \makebox[0pt][l]{\raisebox{\dimexpr #3-\ht0\relax}{\usebox{0}}}%
  \textcolor{black}{\fbox{\rule{0pt}{#3}\rule{\wd0}{0pt}}}%
  \endgroup
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\frameincludegraphicsredcenter}{O{}mO{\ht0}}{%
  \begingroup
  \sbox{0}{\includegraphics[#1]{#2}}%
  \setlength{\fboxrule}{0.3mm}% exaggerated to better see the effect
  \setlength{\fboxsep}{-\fboxrule}%
  \makebox[0pt][l]{\raisebox{.5\dimexpr #3-\ht0\relax}{\usebox{0}}}%
  \textcolor{red}{\fbox{\rule{0pt}{#3}\rule{\wd0}{0pt}}}%
  \endgroup
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\frameincludegraphicsbluecenter}{O{}mO{\ht0}}{%
  \begingroup
  \sbox{0}{\includegraphics[#1]{#2}}%
  \setlength{\fboxrule}{0.3mm}% exaggerated to better see the effect
  \setlength{\fboxsep}{-\fboxrule}%
  \makebox[0pt][l]{\raisebox{.5\dimexpr #3-\ht0\relax}{\usebox{0}}}%
  \textcolor{blue}{\fbox{\rule{0pt}{#3}\rule{\wd0}{0pt}}}%
  \endgroup
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\frameincludegraphicsblackcenter}{O{}mO{\ht0}}{%
  \begingroup
  \sbox{0}{\includegraphics[#1]{#2}}%
  \setlength{\fboxrule}{0.1mm}% exaggerated to better see the effect
  \setlength{\fboxsep}{-\fboxrule}%
  \makebox[0pt][l]{\raisebox{.5\dimexpr #3-\ht0\relax}{\usebox{0}}}%
  \textcolor{black}{\fbox{\rule{0pt}{#3}\rule{\wd0}{0pt}}}%
  \endgroup
}

\newlength{\wantedheight}

\begin{document}

\settoheight{\wantedheight}{\includegraphics[width=\imagewidth,clip]{example-image-a}}% For example use this image for the height. Alternatively you can use every height, you want.

\begin{figure*}[ht]
\centering
\subfloat{
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
    \node[anchor=south east,inner sep=0] (image) at (0,0) {\frameincludegraphicsblue[width=\imagewidth,kit_mocap]{example-image-a}[\wantedheight]};
    \begin{scope}[x={(image.south east)},y={(image.north west)}]
        \node[anchor=south east,draw,fill=white] at (0,0) {Pred};
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}}\imagehspace
\subfloat{
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
    \node[anchor=south east,inner sep=0] (imageb) at (0,0) {\frameincludegraphicsbluetop[width=\imagewidth,kit_mocap]{example-image-a}[\wantedheight]};
    \begin{scope}[x={(image.south east)},y={(image.north west)}]
        \node[anchor=south east,draw,fill=white] at (0,0) {True};
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}}\imagehspace
\subfloat{
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
    \node[anchor=south east,inner sep=0] (image) at (0,0) {\frameincludegraphicsbluecenter[width=\imagewidth,kit_mocap]{example-image-a}[\wantedheight]};
    \begin{scope}[x={(image.south east)},y={(image.north west)}]
        \node[anchor=south east,draw,fill=white] at (0,0) {Pred};
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}}\imagehspace
\subfloat{
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
    \node[anchor=south east,inner sep=0] (imaged) at (0,0) {\frameincludegraphicsblue[width=\imagewidth,clip]{example-image-a}};
    \begin{scope}[x={(image.south east)},y={(image.north west)}]
        \node[anchor=south east,draw,fill=white] at (0,0) {True};
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}}\imagehspace
\subfloat{
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
    \node[anchor=south east,inner sep=0] (image) at (0,0) {\frameincludegraphicsred[width=\imagewidth,clip]{example-image-a}};
    \begin{scope}[x={(image.south east)},y={(image.north west)}]
        \node[anchor=south east,draw,fill=white] at (0,0) {Pred};
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}}\imagehspace
\subfloat{
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
    \node[anchor=south east,inner sep=0] (image6) at (0,0) {\frameincludegraphicsred[width=\imagewidth,clip]{example-image-a}};
    \begin{scope}[x={(image.south east)},y={(image.north west)}]
        \node[anchor=south east,draw,fill=white] at (0,0) {True};
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}}\imagehspace
\subfloat{
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
    \node[anchor=south east,inner sep=0] (image) at (0,0) {\frameincludegraphicsred[width=\imagewidth,clip]{example-image-a}};
    \begin{scope}[x={(image.south east)},y={(image.north west)}]
        \node[anchor=south east,draw,fill=white] at (0,0) {Pred};
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}}\imagehspace
\subfloat{
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
    \node[anchor=south east,inner sep=0] (image) at (0,0) {\frameincludegraphicsred[width=\imagewidth,clip]{example-image-a}};
    \begin{scope}[x={(image.south east)},y={(image.north west)}]
        \node[anchor=south east,draw,fill=white] at (0,0) {True};
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}}

\end{figure*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thank you. But how do I pad the figure from below? i.e. the white space should appear at the bottom. Ive searched for the settoheight function but it doesnt say anything https://ctex.org/documents/latex/latex2e-html/ltx-311.html

Comment: @Kong `\settoheight` is only used to get the wanted reference height in the example. To raise the the image inside the frame you should know the standard LaTeX command `\raisebox`, didn't you? I've added one more example. More and more, however, I doubt that you are really asking what you actually want, or whether the intention is the best. For example, why don't you draw the frames with `tikzpicture` if you use it anyway? Why should the frames partially cover the images? None of this makes any sense to me? You questions are quite strange.

Comment: no i did not know of raisebox

Comment: thank you... i will never understand how people like you can be so proficient with a syntax like latex...

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution and that is to **negative trim** the figure which pads it with whitespace. It does not work with the example-image-a not sure why but it does work with my own images.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{tikz}% loads graphicx
\usepackage{graphicx,xcolor}


\makeatletter
\newcommand{\definetrim}[2]{%
  \define@key{Gin}{#1}[]{\setkeys{Gin}{trim=#2,clip}}%
}
\makeatother

\definetrim{kit_mocap}{0 -10.8cm 0cm 0cm} % {left bottom right top}
%\def\barheight{0.015}
\def\imagewidth{0.12\textwidth}
\def\imagehspace{\hspace{-0.25em}}

\NewDocumentCommand{\frameincludegraphicsred}{O{}mO{\ht0}}{%
  \begingroup
  \sbox{0}{\includegraphics[#1]{#2}}%
  \setlength{\fboxrule}{0.3mm}% exaggerated to better see the effect
  \setlength{\fboxsep}{-\fboxrule}%
  \makebox[0pt][l]{\usebox{0}}%
  \textcolor{red}{\fbox{\rule{0pt}{#3}\rule{\wd0}{0pt}}}%
  \endgroup
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\frameincludegraphicsblue}{O{}mO{\ht0}}{%
  \begingroup
  \sbox{0}{\includegraphics[#1]{#2}}%
  \setlength{\fboxrule}{0.3mm}% exaggerated to better see the effect
  \setlength{\fboxsep}{-\fboxrule}%
  \makebox[0pt][l]{\usebox{0}}%
  \textcolor{blue}{\fbox{\rule{0pt}{#3}\rule{\wd0}{0pt}}}%
  \endgroup
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\frameincludegraphicsblack}{O{}mO{\ht0}}{%
  \begingroup
  \sbox{0}{\includegraphics[#1]{#2}}%
  \setlength{\fboxrule}{0.1mm}% exaggerated to better see the effect
  \setlength{\fboxsep}{-\fboxrule}%
  \makebox[0pt][l]{\usebox{0}}%
  \textcolor{black}{\fbox{\rule{0pt}{#3}\rule{\wd0}{0pt}}}%
  \endgroup
}

\newlength{\wantedheight}

\begin{document}

\settoheight{\wantedheight}{\includegraphics[width=\imagewidth,clip]{example-image-a}}

\begin{figure*}[ht]
\centering
\subfloat{
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
    \node[anchor=south east,inner sep=0] (image) at (0,0) {\frameincludegraphicsblue[width=\imagewidth,kit_mocap,clip]{2.46_right_pred.png}};
    \begin{scope}[x={(image.south east)},y={(image.north west)}]
        \node[anchor=south east,draw,fill=white] at (0,0) {Pred};
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}}\imagehspace
\subfloat{
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
    \node[anchor=south east,inner sep=0] (imageb) at (0,0) {\frameincludegraphicsblue[width=\imagewidth,clip]{2.46_left_pred.png}};
    \begin{scope}[x={(image.south east)},y={(image.north west)}]
        \node[anchor=south east,draw,fill=white] at (0,0) {True};
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}}\imagehspace
\subfloat{
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
    \node[anchor=south east,inner sep=0] (image) at (0,0) {\frameincludegraphicsblue[width=\imagewidth,clip]{example-image-a}};
    \begin{scope}[x={(image.south east)},y={(image.north west)}]
        \node[anchor=south east,draw,fill=white] at (0,0) {Pred};
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}}\imagehspace
\subfloat{
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
    \node[anchor=south east,inner sep=0] (imaged) at (0,0) {\frameincludegraphicsblue[width=\imagewidth,clip]{example-image-a}};
    \begin{scope}[x={(image.south east)},y={(image.north west)}]
        \node[anchor=south east,draw,fill=white] at (0,0) {True};
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}}\imagehspace
\subfloat{
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
    \node[anchor=south east,inner sep=0] (image) at (0,0) {\frameincludegraphicsred[width=\imagewidth,clip]{example-image-a}};
    \begin{scope}[x={(image.south east)},y={(image.north west)}]
        \node[anchor=south east,draw,fill=white] at (0,0) {Pred};
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}}\imagehspace
\subfloat{
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
    \node[anchor=south east,inner sep=0] (image6) at (0,0) {\frameincludegraphicsred[width=\imagewidth,clip]{example-image-a}};
    \begin{scope}[x={(image.south east)},y={(image.north west)}]
        \node[anchor=south east,draw,fill=white] at (0,0) {True};
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}}\imagehspace
\subfloat{
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
    \node[anchor=south east,inner sep=0] (image) at (0,0) {\frameincludegraphicsred[width=\imagewidth,clip]{example-image-a}};
    \begin{scope}[x={(image.south east)},y={(image.north west)}]
        \node[anchor=south east,draw,fill=white] at (0,0) {Pred};
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}}\imagehspace
\subfloat{
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
    \node[anchor=south east,inner sep=0] (image) at (0,0) {\frameincludegraphicsred[width=\imagewidth,clip]{example-image-a}};
    \begin{scope}[x={(image.south east)},y={(image.north west)}]
        \node[anchor=south east,draw,fill=white] at (0,0) {True};
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}}

\end{figure*}

\end{document}
```