# Negative trim all images to a reference height (\textheight)

Tags: tikz-pgf, floats

I have a list of images that do not have the same shape. I would like to pad from below (negative trim) the images so that they all have the same shape. How would I do this? Here is my MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{tikz}% loads graphicx
\usepackage{graphicx,xcolor}

\begin{document}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\definetrim}[2]{%
  \define@key{Gin}{#1}[]{\setkeys{Gin}{trim=#2,clip}}%
}
\makeatother

\definetrim{kit_mocap}{0 0 0 3cm} % {left bottom right top}
%\def\barheight{0.015}
\def\imagewidth{0.12\textwidth}
\def\imagehspace{\hspace{-0.25em}}

\NewDocumentCommand{\frameincludegraphicsred}{O{}m}{%
  \begingroup
  \sbox{0}{\includegraphics[#1]{#2}}%
  \setlength{\fboxrule}{0.3mm}% exaggerated to better see the effect
  \setlength{\fboxsep}{-\fboxrule}%
  \makebox[0pt][l]{\usebox{0}}%
  \textcolor{red}{\fbox{\rule{0pt}{\ht0}\rule{\wd0}{0pt}}}%
  \endgroup
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\frameincludegraphicsblue}{O{}m}{%
  \begingroup
  \sbox{0}{\includegraphics[#1]{#2}}%
  \setlength{\fboxrule}{0.3mm}% exaggerated to better see the effect
  \setlength{\fboxsep}{-\fboxrule}%
  \makebox[0pt][l]{\usebox{0}}%
  \textcolor{blue}{\fbox{\rule{0pt}{\ht0}\rule{\wd0}{0pt}}}%
  \endgroup
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\frameincludegraphicsblack}{O{}m}{%
  \begingroup
  \sbox{0}{\includegraphics[#1]{#2}}%
  \setlength{\fboxrule}{0.1mm}% exaggerated to better see the effect
  \setlength{\fboxsep}{-\fboxrule}%
  \makebox[0pt][l]{\usebox{0}}%
  \textcolor{black}{\fbox{\rule{0pt}{\ht0}\rule{\wd0}{0pt}}}%
  \endgroup
}

\begin{figure*}[ht]
\centering
\subfloat{
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
    \node[anchor=south east,inner sep=0] (image) at (0,0) {\frameincludegraphicsblue[width=\imagewidth,kit_mocap]{example-image-a}};
    \begin{scope}[x={(image.south east)},y={(image.north west)}]
        \node[anchor=south east,draw,fill=white] at (0,0) {Pred};
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}}\imagehspace
\subfloat{
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
    \node[anchor=south east,inner sep=0] (imageb) at (0,0) {\frameincludegraphicsblue[width=\imagewidth,clip]{example-image-a}};
    \begin{scope}[x={(image.south east)},y={(image.north west)}]
        \node[anchor=south east,draw,fill=white] at (0,0) {True};
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}}\imagehspace
\subfloat{
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
    \node[anchor=south east,inner sep=0] (image) at (0,0) {\frameincludegraphicsblue[width=\imagewidth,clip]{example-image-a}};
    \begin{scope}[x={(image.south east)},y={(image.north west)}]
        \node[anchor=south east,draw,fill=white] at (0,0) {Pred};
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}}\imagehspace
\subfloat{
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
    \node[anchor=south east,inner sep=0] (imaged) at (0,0) {\frameincludegraphicsblue[width=\imagewidth,clip]{example-image-a}};
    \begin{scope}[x={(image.south east)},y={(image.north west)}]
        \node[anchor=south east,draw,fill=white] at (0,0) {True};
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}}\imagehspace
\subfloat{
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
    \node[anchor=south east,inner sep=0] (image) at (0,0) {\frameincludegraphicsred[width=\imagewidth,clip]{example-image-a}};
    \begin{scope}[x={(image.south east)},y={(image.north west)}]
        \node[anchor=south east,draw,fill=white] at (0,0) {Pred};
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}}\imagehspace
\subfloat{
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
    \node[anchor=south east,inner sep=0] (image6) at (0,0) {\frameincludegraphicsred[width=\imagewidth,clip]{example-image-a}};
    \begin{scope}[x={(image.south east)},y={(image.north west)}]
        \node[anchor=south east,draw,fill=white] at (0,0) {True};
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}}\imagehspace
\subfloat{
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
    \node[anchor=south east,inner sep=0] (image) at (0,0) {\frameincludegraphicsred[width=\imagewidth,clip]{example-image-a}};
    \begin{scope}[x={(image.south east)},y={(image.north west)}]
        \node[anchor=south east,draw,fill=white] at (0,0) {Pred};
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}}\imagehspace
\subfloat{
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
    \node[anchor=south east,inner sep=0] (image) at (0,0) {\frameincludegraphicsred[width=\imagewidth,clip]{example-image-a}};
    \begin{scope}[x={(image.south east)},y={(image.north west)}]
        \node[anchor=south east,draw,fill=white] at (0,0) {True};
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}}

\end{figure*}

\end{document}
```

and here is a snippet of my attempt. I define a variable `referenceheight` which is `0.08\textheight` which is the height version of `\textwidth`. 0.08 because 1/12 > 0.08 and I have 12 figures. Then I simply negative pad the image. It doesnt work.

```
\def\referenceheight{0.08\textheight}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
    \node[anchor=south east,inner sep=0] (image) at (0,0) {\frameincludegraphicsblue[width=\imagewidth,pad=0 -\referenceheight 0 0,clip]{example-image-a}};
    \begin{scope}[x={(image.south east)},y={(image.north west)}]
        \node[anchor=south east,draw,fill=white] at (0,0) {Pred};
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: You can again use the `\frameincludegraphics…top` commands from my answer to [your previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/684096/how-to-pad-image-such-that-the-frame-has-the-same-size).

Comment: @cabohah im sorry im a complete idiot

Answer (score 1):

Just an idea. You can include your images into `equal size group` tcolorboxes and let that `tcolorbox` package does the work for you.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\tcbset{ size=tight, width=3cm, nobeforeafter, equal height group, halign=center}

\begin{document}
\begin{tcolorbox}
\includegraphics[height=2cm]{example-image-A}
\end{tcolorbox}%
\begin{tcolorbox}
\includegraphics[height=1cm]{example-image-B}
\end{tcolorbox}%
\begin{tcolorbox}
\includegraphics[height=1.7cm]{example-image-c}
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

[image]